# Moving New files from one linux server to other linux FTP

Tags: ftp, centos

Here i have tow Servers(CentOS):

```
1- WebServer    2-FTP Server
```

in **webserver** with directory of **/var/www/document** is located all documents of website(pdf,images,xls...)

Now i want the **web server** to transfer any new file to **FTP server** every day at one time and only copy the file which are not exist on ftp server

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For linux to rsync from one System to other:

```
1- System1  = 10.0.0.1
2- System2  = 10.0.0.2
```

first of all we need to add trust between tow servers means they should login with each other with out re authentication:
http://www.tecmint.com/ssh-passwordless-login-using-ssh-keygen-in-5-easy-steps/

from 10.0.0.1 we need to rsync to 10.0.0.2 one directory for example only **smb** directory. location for smb = /smb in 10.0.0.1

first we need to set a job in **crontab**

```
10.0.0.1#crontab -e
```

this will open crontab and add the line bellow:

```
PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/scripts/
01 17 * * *   sh /script/scriptone.sh
```

the timing
01 -> means hour 
17 -> means minut
other tree stare is days of the week(you can search crontab timing on google)

Now create the script file, lastly we set it's path on crontab

```
vi /script/scriptone.sh
```

add these lines to scriptone.sh

```
rsync -avzhe ssh /smb/* root@10.0.0.2/smb/
```

save and exit

now you can simple wait for the crontab time or just move to the

```
cd /script
sh scriptone.sh
```

now check the 10.0.0.2 and see all files from 10.0.0.1:/smb is copied

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like rsync will be a better way to go.[enter link description here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync)
rsync can be used both to push and pull files (from / to server) depending on ur needs, and allows to specificy matching rules like: only stuff from last day like you'll need.